# Draw a plane in space and a coordinate system using TiKz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Suppose I have a plane `E: a*x_1 + b*x_2 + c*x_3 = d` (a,..,d should be concrete numbers) in space and a point P. Is there a way to draw a 3-d coordinate system, E, P and perpendicular line to E through P?

Comment: How do you want the plane to be drawn?

Comment: Perhaps one need to distinguish different cases: If the plane intersects all three coordinate axis, I want to connect those intersection points and draw the resulting triangle. If this is not the case I want to have something like [this](http://media.4teachers.de/images/thumbs/image_thumb.4336.png)

Answer (score 20):

TikZ has a built-in 3d coordinate system. You can set the directions of the unit vectors with the `x`, `y` and `z` options. Then you could just do the math by hand and draw the points and lines. Or, you can define some macros to do the job:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter

% Set some defaults 
\tikzset{
    plane max x/.initial=2,
    plane max y/.initial=2,
    plane max z/.initial=2
}

\tikzset{plane/.style={fill opacity=0.5}}

% Define a plane.
% #1 = name of the plane
% #2*x + #3*y + #4*z = #5 is the equation of the plane
\newcommand*\definePlaneByEquation[5]{
    \expandafter\gdef\csname tsx@plane@#1\endcsname{
        \def\tsx@plane@xcoeff{#2}
        \def\tsx@plane@ycoeff{#3}
        \def\tsx@plane@zcoeff{#4}
        \def\tsx@plane@scalar{#5}
    }
}

% Draw a plane.
% The optional first argument is passed as options to TikZ.
% The mandatory second argument is the name of the plane.
\newcommand\drawPlane[2][]{
    \tikzset{plane max x/.get=\tsx@plane@maxx}
    \tikzset{plane max y/.get=\tsx@plane@maxy}
    \tikzset{plane max z/.get=\tsx@plane@maxz}
    \csname tsx@plane@#2\endcsname

    \ifdim\tsx@plane@xcoeff pt=0pt
        \ifdim\tsx@plane@ycoeff pt=0pt
            \ifdim\tsx@plane@zcoeff pt=0pt
                %invalid plane
            \else % x=0, y=0
                \filldraw[plane,#1,shift={(0,0,\tsx@plane@scalar/\tsx@plane@zcoeff)}]
                    (0,0,0) --
                    (\tsx@plane@maxx,0,0) --
                    (\tsx@plane@maxx,\tsx@plane@maxy,0) --
                    (0,\tsx@plane@maxy,0) --
                    cycle;
            \fi
        \else % x=0, y != 0
            \ifdim\tsx@plane@zcoeff pt=0pt % x=0, z=0
                \filldraw[plane,#1,shift={(0,\tsx@plane@scalar/\tsx@plane@ycoeff,0)}]
                    (0,0,0) --
                    (\tsx@plane@maxx,0,0) --
                    (\tsx@plane@maxx,0,\tsx@plane@maxz) --
                    (0,0,\tsx@plane@maxz) --
                    cycle;
            \else % x=0
                \filldraw[plane,#1]
                    (0,\tsx@plane@scalar/\tsx@plane@ycoeff,0) --
                    (0,0,\tsx@plane@scalar/\tsx@plane@zcoeff) --
                    (\tsx@plane@maxx,0,\tsx@plane@scalar/\tsx@plane@zcoeff) --
                    (\tsx@plane@maxx,\tsx@plane@scalar/\tsx@plane@ycoeff,0) --
                    cycle;
            \fi
        \fi
    \else % x!=0
        \ifdim\tsx@plane@ycoeff pt=0pt % x!=0,y=0
            \ifdim\tsx@plane@zcoeff pt=0pt % x!=0,y=0,z=0
                \filldraw[plane,#1,shift={(\tsx@plane@scalar/\tsx@plane@xcoeff,0,0)}]
                    (0,0,0) --
                    (0,0,\tsx@plane@maxz) --
                    (0,\tsx@plane@maxy,\tsx@plane@maxz) --
                    (0,\tsx@plane@maxy,0) --
                    cycle;
            \else % x!=0,y=0,z!=0
                \filldraw[plane,#1]
                    (\tsx@plane@scalar/\tsx@plane@xcoeff,0) --
                    (0,0,\tsx@plane@scalar/\tsx@plane@zcoeff) --
                    (0,\tsx@plane@maxy,\tsx@plane@scalar/\tsx@plane@zcoeff) --
                    (\tsx@plane@scalar/\tsx@plane@xcoeff,\tsx@plane@maxy,0) --
                    cycle;
            \fi
        \else % x!=0,y!=0
            \ifdim\tsx@plane@zcoeff pt=0pt % x!=0,y!=0,z=0
                \filldraw[plane,#1]
                    (\tsx@plane@scalar/\tsx@plane@xcoeff,0) --
                    (0,\tsx@plane@scalar/\tsx@plane@ycoeff,0) --
                    (0,\tsx@plane@scalar/\tsx@plane@ycoeff,\tsx@plane@maxz) --
                    (\tsx@plane@scalar/\tsx@plane@xcoeff,0,\tsx@plane@maxz) --
                    cycle;
            \else % x!=0,y!=0,z!=0
                \filldraw[plane,#1]
                    (\tsx@plane@scalar/\tsx@plane@xcoeff,0,0) --
                    (0,\tsx@plane@scalar/\tsx@plane@ycoeff,0) --
                    (0,0,\tsx@plane@scalar/\tsx@plane@zcoeff) --
                    cycle;
            \fi
        \fi
    \fi
}

% Define a point.
% #1 = name of the point
% (#2,#3,#4) is the location.
% Also creates a coordinate node of name #1 at the location.
\newcommand\definePointByXYZ[4]{
    \coordinate (#1) at (#2,#3,#4);
    \expandafter\gdef\csname tsx@point@#1\endcsname{
        \def\tsx@point@x{#2}
        \def\tsx@point@y{#3}
        \def\tsx@point@z{#4}
    }
}

% Project a point to a plane.
% #1 = name of the new point
% #2 = name of old point
% #3 = name of plane
\newcommand\projectPointToPlane[3]{{
    \csname tsx@point@#2\endcsname
    \csname tsx@plane@#3\endcsname

    % square of norm of the normal vector
    \pgfmathparse{\tsx@plane@xcoeff*\tsx@plane@xcoeff + \tsx@plane@ycoeff*\tsx@plane@ycoeff + \tsx@plane@zcoeff*\tsx@plane@zcoeff}
    \let\nnormsq\pgfmathresult

    % Calculate distance in terms of the (non-normalized) normal vector
    \pgfmathparse{(\tsx@point@x*\tsx@plane@xcoeff + \tsx@point@y*\tsx@plane@ycoeff + \tsx@point@z*\tsx@plane@zcoeff - \tsx@plane@scalar) / \nnormsq}
    \let\distance\pgfmathresult

    % Calculate point
    \pgfmathparse{\tsx@point@x - \distance*\tsx@plane@xcoeff}
    \let\x\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathparse{\tsx@point@y - \distance*\tsx@plane@ycoeff}
    \let\y\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathparse{\tsx@point@z - \distance*\tsx@plane@zcoeff}
    \let\z\pgfmathresult

    \definePointByXYZ{#1}{\x}{\y}{\z}
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(240:0.8cm)}, y={(-10:1cm)}, z={(0,1cm)},
        plane max z=3]
    \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (3,0,0);
    \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,3,0);
    \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3);

    \definePlaneByEquation{myplane}{1}{1.5}{0}{2}
    \drawPlane[thick,fill=blue]{myplane}

    \definePointByXYZ{mypoint}{1}{1.5}{2};
    \draw (mypoint) circle [radius=1pt];

    \projectPointToPlane{proj}{mypoint}{myplane}
    \fill (proj) circle [radius=1pt];

    \draw[->, shorten <=1pt,shorten >=1pt] (mypoint) -- (proj);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: project a point to a plane]

Some comments:

- I hope I didn't mess up some case.
- With the `plane max x`/`y`/`z` options, you can specify how far a plane with zero parameters should extend.
- If you want to draw a line through the point, normal to the plane, you can use

  ```
  \definePlaneByEquation{myplane}{1}{1.5}{0}{2}
  \definePointByXYZ{mypoint}{1}{1.5}{2};
  \projectPointToPlane{proj}{mypoint}{myplane}

  \draw ($(proj)!-2cm!(mypoint)$) -- (proj);
  \drawPlane[thick,fill=blue]{myplane}
  \draw (proj) -- ($(mypoint)!-2cm!(proj)$);
  ```

  The order is important to get correct overpainting in case the plane is opaque or the line is non-black.
- The tests for 0 should really be tests for being smaller than epsilon.
- Maybe it would be useful to apply `\pgfmathparse` to the arguments of the definition macros.

Comment: Fine! It's a good starting point. I started a package about 3D geometry and this answer is interesting.

Comment: @Astramundus, do you know the `tikz-3dplot` package? I use it all the time, might also be a good source for your 3d package? Check it out at: http://archive.cs.uu.nl/mirror/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-3dplot/tikz-3dplot_documentation.pdf

Comment: @Altermundus: I was wondering whether I should invest more time in this and add more things for 3D geometry (e.g. intersect various things) or if you are already working on a 3D version of TkZ.

Comment: @romeovs: `tikz-3dplot` is nice, but as far as I am aware it doesn't have features to define planes and do intersections and such.

Comment: @romeovs Yes :) but the author of the `tikz-3dplot` package uses some of my ideas. The author found interesting my "annotated-3d-box" example on texample.net: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/annotated-3d-box/

Comment: @Caramdir I have some codes inside a tkz-3d.sty but actually I worked a lot on Euclidean geometry and graphs theory but now I can invest more time on the 3D geometry but something about planes, pyramids, cubes and parallelepiped because It's hard to calculate with TikZ. Perhaps with lua and tikz ?

Comment: Well done. But perhaps you could edit your code for supporting rotating the planes. I'm thinking in this [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278709/draw-an-intersection-of-two-planes). Can we pass a "rotation" parameter?

Comment: @Caramdir Really appreciate your answer, it's exactly what I've been looking for. Any chance you could answer [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348842/how-to-calculate-with-two-same-macros-in-pgfmath) question?:)

Comment: First of all thank you for this great piece of code. There's just a tiny problem: if I call \projectPointToPlane with a point defined by a previous call to the same command (e.g. I'm trying to find the projection on plane B of the projection on plane A of a point), LaTeX says "Undefined control sequence \tsx@point@x ->\x" for all 3 coords. Using just { ... } for defining the command works but then the definition of the first projection is no longer correct (becomes equals to the second one). Can the code be easily fixed?

Comment: Can it just draw 2x+3y+4z+5=0 without so many declarations?