# How to draw this pyramid with TeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I draw this pyramid with GeoSpacw. How to draw this figure with TeX?

[image]

Where:

- *M* is midpoint of the segment *SA*;
- *I* is midpoint of the segment *SD*;
- *H* is project of the point *A* on the line *SO*;
- *ABKE* is a is a parallelogram;
- The line passing through *S* and parallel to the line *AB*.

Comment: M doesn't appear to be on segment SB.  Do you mean SA or SN?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what points are given, and what points are calculated?  As it stands, it seems like ABKE is an arbitrary parallelogram and S is an arbitrary point (from which we can calculate M and N).  It seems like there needs to be some extra information to get I, D or C.

Comment: O.K. The line SA perpendicular to the plane (ABC). SA = AB*\Sqrt{2}$, ABCD is a square. K is projection of B on the plane (SCD). Thank you.

Comment: I need some verifications. E seems to the orthogonal projection of A on SD because BK//AE and K is the orthogonal projection of B on SCD. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**General Update**

I can suggest two answers, the first one with [`tikz-3dplot`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-3dplot) interesting because we draw the pyramid in 3D and we can change easily the point of view and the perspective; the second one with [`tkz-euclide`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-euclide) in 2D with parallel projection.

I made some mistakes in my first calculations but there are two problems to draw a correct figure. The first problem is to place E and K, the second one is to place H. The methods  depend of the tools used, 3D or 2D with parallel projection.

**How to place K and E**

BK is orthogonal to the plane SCD, ABKE is a parallelogram, so AE||BK then AE is orthogonal to SCD.
AE is perpendicular to SD in the plane ASD. This method is useful with with parallel projection because ASD is the main front and is in the main plane. We can use a projection in a plane to place E.

In 3D with for example  `tikz-3dplot` we need to calculate the coordinate of E. I named `\a` the side of the square ABCD.

[image]

The coordinates of E are `(0,2*\a/3,sqrt(2)/3*\a)`.
*Remark*: If the coordinates of K are `(xK,yK,zK)` then the coordinates of E are `(0,yK,zK)`. Or xK=xB, so K is defined by `(\a,2*\a/3,sqrt(2)/3*\a)`.

About K. In the first answer, I used the code  from  of Caramdir's answer (from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19972/draw-a-plane-in-space-and-a-coordinate-system-using-tikz/20009#20009)). If you know the equation of a plane, it's possible to determine the orthognal projection of a point on this plane. I determined the coordinates of K, so I can avoid the interesting code of Caramdir.
*Remark*: SCD has an simple equation here `sqrt(2)y+z = sqrt(2)\s` it's parallel to (AB) and cut axis in S and D. It's easy to get K with caramdir's code.

**How to place H**

H is the projection orthogonal of A on OS. OAS is orthogonal to ABCD. The projection orthognal of H on ABBCD is a point Q on the line OA. Below I determined the coordinates of Q `(2/5 \a,2/5 /a,0)`and then I determined the coordinates of H. It's not possible to use the orthogonal projection of TikZ.

[image]

**Part 1) With `tikz-3dplot`**

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
 \usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}


 \tikzset{ hidden/.style = {thin, dotted}}
   \tikzset{%
     add/.style args={#1 and #2}{
         to path={%
  ($(\tikztostart)!-#1!(\tikztotarget)$)--($(\tikztotarget)!-#2!(\tikztostart)$)%
   \tikztonodes}}}

 \begin{document}

 %\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{120}
  \tdplotsetmaincoords{80}{100} 
 \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=2]
 \pgfmathsetmacro\a{2}

 % definitions 
    \path (0,0,0)                           coordinate (A) 
          (\a,0,0)                          coordinate (B) 
          (\a,\a,0)                         coordinate (C) 
          (0,\a,0)                          coordinate (D) 
          (0,0,{\a*sqrt(2)})                coordinate (S) 
          (0,0,{0.5*\a*sqrt(2)})            coordinate (M) 
          (0.5*\a,0.5*\a,0)                 coordinate (O) 
          (0,0.5*\a,{0.5*\a*sqrt(2)})       coordinate (I) 
          (2/5*\a,2/5*\a,{sqrt(2)/5*\a})    coordinate (H)
          ($(B)!2!(M)$)                     coordinate (N)
          (0,2*\a/3,{sqrt(2)/3*\a})         coordinate (E)
           (\a,2*\a/3,{sqrt(2)/3*\a})        coordinate (K) ;
 % drawing
 \begin{scope}
    \clip (S) -- (B) -- (D) --cycle;
    \draw[hidden] (B) -- (N);
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}
    \clip (S) -- (I) -- (N) --cycle;
    \draw (B) -- (N);
 \end{scope}

 \draw[hidden] 
       (A) -- (C)  (A) -- (B)  (A) -- (D) (A) -- (H) (A) -- (S)
      (A) -- (E) (B) -- (D)  (O) -- (S) (I) -- (M);
 \draw (B) -- (K) -- (E)   (C) -- (N) -- (K)
       (B) --(C) -- (D) (S) -- (D)  (S) -- (B)  (S) -- (C);
 \draw[add = 1 and 1]  (S) to (N); 

 % place black circles and labels
 \foreach \point/\position in {A/left,B/left,C/right,D/right,E/right,H/above,
   I/right,K/right,M/right,N/left,O/right,S/left}
 {
   \fill (\point) circle (.5pt);
   \node[\position=3pt] at (\point) {$\point$};
 }

 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to change the point of view you can try `\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{120}`.

[image]

**Part B) with `tkz-euclide`**

If you want to use only TikZ, see Gonzalo's answer. The problem are the same, only the syntax and the macros are different. But the answers are similar. It's not very easy to show 3D objects with 2D methods.

I use the projection of A on SD to get E but it's also possible to get the coordinates. It's more difficult to get H, I used here the fact SO=5*OH.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tkz-euclide,amsmath} 
 \usetkzobj{all} 
 \tikzset{hidden/.style = {thin, dotted}}
 \begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzInit[xmin=-5,xmax=10,ymin=-5,ymax=15]
   \tkzClip
  \pgfmathsetmacro\zs{3+5*sqrt(2)}
  % definition
  \tkzDefPoints{0/0/B,1/3/A,5/0/C,6/3/D,1/\zs/S}
  \tkzDefMidPoint(A,C)                      \tkzGetPoint{O}
  \tkzDefMidPoint(S,A)                      \tkzGetPoint{M}
  \tkzDefMidPoint(S,D)                      \tkzGetPoint{I}
  \tkzDefPointBy[projection=onto S--D](A)   \tkzGetPoint{E} 
  \tkzDefPointWith[colinear= at E](A,B)     \tkzGetPoint{K}
  \tkzDefPointWith[linear,K=2](C,I)         \tkzGetPoint{N}
  \tkzDefPointWith[linear,K=1/5](O,S)       \tkzGetPoint{H}
 % drawing 
  \tkzDrawSegments[hidden](A,B A,D I,M A,C B,D S,O M,E A,E A,S  A,H)
  \tkzDrawSegments(B,C C,D B,S S,D B,K K,E C,N K,N)
   \begin{scope}
       \tkzClipPolygon(S,B,D) 
       \tkzDrawSegments[hidden](B,N)
   \end{scope}
   \begin{scope}
      \tkzClipPolygon(S,I,N) 
       \tkzDrawSegments(B,N)
   \end{scope}
   % labels
    \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,D,S,I,M,O,E,K,N,H)
    \tkzLabelPoints(A,B,C,D,K,O)
    \tkzLabelPoints[above](S,E,N,H)
    \tkzLabelPoints[above right](I,M)
    \tkzMarkRightAngles(A,E,D D,A,S)
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The coordinates of the point $H$ is $(2/5a, 2/5a, \frac{sqrt(2)}{5}a$.

Comment: @minthao_2011 Thanks to confirm my calculations !

Answer (score 15):

With PSTricks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\psset{linejoin=1}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-.75,-.75)(5.75,9.75)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={-135,-45,0,180,180,0}]
        {B}(4,0){C}(5,2){D}(1,2){A}(1,7){S}([nodesep=1.8]{S}D){E}
    \pstMiddleAB{D}{B}{O}
    \pstTranslation[PosAngle=30]{A}{B}{E}[K]
    \pstProjection{O}{S}{A}[H]
    \pstMiddleAB[PosAngle=-45]{S}{A}{M}
    \pstMiddleAB{S}{D}{I}
    \pstInterLL{B}{M}{C}{I}{N}
    \pstInterLL[PointName=none,PointSymbol=none]{D}{S}{B}{N}{X}
    \psline(B)(C)(D)
    \psline(B)(K)(E)
    \psline(B)(S)(D)
    \psline(C)(N)(K)
    \psline(X)(N)
    \pcline[nodesepA=-2,nodesepB=-.5](S)(N)
    \psset{linestyle=dashed}
    \pspolygon(A)(B)(D)
    \pspolygon(A)(C)(D)
    \psline(A)(S)(O)
    \psline(H)(A)(E)
    \psline(M)(I)
    \psline(B)(X)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The point E is defined with K. It seems that you define E and then K. I don't understand `([nodesep=1.8]{S}D){E}`

Comment: Are you sure of the `psprojection`. It is not a drawing in a plane, If S is on a line perpendicular to ABCD in O,  the projection is false but perhaps I'm wrong.

Comment: If BK is orthogonal to the plane SCD then AE is orthogonal to SCD to. The consequence is AE perpendicular to SD, E is the orthogonal projection of A on SD.

Comment: To se the problem with the projection :     \pstTranslation[PosAngle=30]{A}{S}{O}[P]
    \pstProjection{O}{P}{A}[Q] OP is orthogonal to ABCD so the projection orthogonal Q of A on OP is O.  Then ABKE is a parallelogram and BK is orthogonal to SCD, so AE is orthogonal to SCD. The consequence is AE perpendicular to SD because A,E,S,D ar in the same plane. I think it's not the case in your construction

Comment: I'm not a great expert of pstricks and pst-eucl but I would like to understand how you place E. I'm not sure that you place E to the right place. pstProjection seems to be a macro to use in 2D but in the main plane ASD or a plane parallel to ASD.

Answer (score 10):

Here's one possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,intersections,calc}

\def\xmov{0.8cm}
\def\ymov{3cm}
\def\xside{4.5cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (-0.5,-0.5) rectangle (5.7,12.1);
\coordinate (b);
\coordinate[above right=\ymov and \xmov of b] (a);
\coordinate[right=\xside of b] (c);
\coordinate[right=\xside of a] (d);
\coordinate[above=6cm of a] (s);
\draw (b) -- (s) -- (c);
\draw[name path=edge1] (s) -- (d);
\draw[dashed] (b) -- (a) -- (d) -- (c) -- (b) -- (d);
\draw[dashed,name path=diag1] (b) -- (d);
\draw[dashed,name path=diag2] (a) -- (c);
\draw[dashed] (s) -- (a);
\coordinate[name intersections={of=diag1 and diag2,by={o}}];
\draw[dashed] (s) -- (o);
\coordinate (i) at ( $ (s)!0.5!(d) $ );
\coordinate (m) at ( $ (s)!0.5!(a) $ );
\path[dashed,name path=line1] (b) -- ( $ (b)!15cm!(m) $ );
\path[draw,name path=line2] (c) -- ( $ (c)!15cm!(i) $ );
\coordinate[name intersections={of=line1 and line2,by={n}}];
% intersection od sd with nb
\coordinate[name intersections={of=line1 and edge1,by={aux}}];
\coordinate (e) at ( $ (d)!(a)!(s) $ );
\coordinate[below left=\ymov and \xmov of e] (k);
\coordinate (h) at ($(s)!(a)!(o)$);
\draw (n) -- (aux);
\draw[dashed] (aux) -- (b);
\draw[dashed] (a) -- (h);
\draw (e) -- (k) -- (b);
\draw[dashed] (e) -- (a);
\draw (n) -- (k);
\draw (n) -- ( $ (n)!6cm!(s) $ );
% place black circles and labels
\foreach \point/\position in {a/left,b/left,c/right,d/right,e/right,h/above left,
  i/right,k/right,m/right,n/left,o/right,s/left}
{
  \fill (\point) circle (2pt);
  \node[\position=2pt] at (\point) {$\point$};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Midpoints were obtained using `($(s)!0.5!(o)$)` and the projection was obtained with `($(s)!(a)!(o)$)`. Intersections were calculated with the `intersections` library.

Changing `dashed` to `dotted` everywhere in the code above one gets:

[image]

Comment: Hi Gonzalo. I think with this method you can't respect the request like : as=sqrt(2)ab and h projection of a on ao. Here you get the projection in a plane, if s is above o, I think you get a problem because the projection needs to be o.

Comment: And it's not Sb perpendicular to bc but Sa perpendicular to ad.

Comment: @AlainMatthes yes, but the OP kept adding new conditions after I had answered with the initial requirements. Maybe I'll update this with the new requirements, but still it's not clear to me how to determine some of the points.

Comment: The main problem is `($(s)!(a)!(o)$)` because aso is not a plane parallel to asd. If my calculations are correct, oh = os/5.

Comment: Hi, @AlainMatthes. I see that you took the time to make the calculations; thanks; I didn't feel like doing them myself ;-) I'll use your result about `oh` and `os`, if it's OK with you.

Comment: It's Ok if the calculations are fine :) but I need a confirmation (I made some mistakes in my first calculations)

Answer (score 10):

[image]

`Asymptote` version `pyramid.asy`:

```
import three;  // 3D module
import math;
currentprojection=orthographic(camera=(55,144,80),
  up=(0,0,1),target=(0,0,0),zoom=1,center=true);

size(300);
size3(300,300,300);

triple intersectionpoint(triple a,triple b,triple c,triple d){
  real u=((d.x-c.x)*a.y+(c.y-d.y)*a.x+c.x*d.y-d.x*c.y)/
      ((d.y-c.y)*b.x+(c.x-d.x)*b.y+(d.x-c.x)*a.y+(c.y-d.y)*a.x);
  return a*(1.0-u)+b*u;
}

triple A,B,C,D,EE,II,H,K,M,NN,O,SS;  // S,E and N has special meaning in asy:
                                    // as South, East and North or (0,-1), (1,0) and (0,1)
                                    // and I is a sqrt(-1)=(0,1)                                    
real a=40;    // side of the square;
real h=50;    // height, h=AS
real d=sqrt(2)/2*a;  // half of the diagonal

O=(0,0,0);
C=(0,d,0);
B=(d,0,0);
A=(0,-d,0);
D=(-d,0,0);
SS=A+(0,0,h);
M=0.5(SS+A);
II=0.5(SS+D);
NN=intersectionpoint(SS,(SS+A-B),C,II);

real phi=atan(h/a);
real u=a*cos(phi)/sqrt(a^2+h^2);
EE=D*(1-u)+SS*u;
K=EE+B-A;

real psi=atan(h/d);
real u=d*cos(psi)/sqrt(d^2+h^2);
H=O*(1-u)+SS*u;

pair Q=intersectionpoint(project(NN--B),project(SS--D));

pen dashed=linetype(new real[] {5,5}); // set up dashed pattern
pen visLine=darkblue+0.8pt;
pen hidLine=lightblue+dashed+0.8pt;

void Dot(...triple[] v){
  dotfactor=8;
  for(int i=0;i<v.length;++i){
    dot(project(v[i]),UnFill);
  }
}

void Draw3(guide3 g, pen p=currentpen){
  draw(project(g),p);
}

void labelP(string s,triple t,pair p=(0,0)){
  label("$"+s+"$",project(t),p);
}

Draw3(B--A--D,hidLine);
Draw3(H--A--SS,hidLine);
Draw3(M--II,hidLine);
Draw3(EE--A--C,hidLine);
Draw3(B--D,hidLine);
Draw3(SS--O,hidLine);

Draw3(SS--B--C--SS--D--C,visLine);
Draw3(SS--NN--C,visLine);
Draw3(EE--K--B,visLine);
Draw3(NN--K,visLine);

draw(project(NN)--Q,visLine);
draw(project(B)--Q,hidLine);

Dot(A,B,C,D,EE,H,II,K,M,NN,O,SS);

labelP("A",A,NW);
labelP("B",B,SW);
labelP("C",C,E);
labelP("D",D,NE);
labelP("E",EE,NE);
labelP("H",H,NE);
labelP("I",II,NE);
labelP("K",K,SE);
labelP("M",M,W);
labelP("N",NN,W);
labelP("O",O,S);
labelP("S",SS,NW);
```

To get a standalone `pyramid.pdf` run `asy -f pdf pyramid.asy`.

Comment: +1 and please kindly make asymptote version for [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11390/19356).

Comment: @Bugbusters: done.

Comment: Best looking solution to this question.

Comment: @g.kov I like this method.

Comment: @g.kov Can the dashed be drawn automatically? In your code, I think, you did by hand.

Comment: @minhthien_2016: Yes, the choice of `visLine/hidLine` pen
was made by hand. Automatic tracing of the lines is possible in principle,
especially for simple 3d scenes like this one,
but in general it very quickly becomes overcomplicated.

Comment: @g.kov And here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481283/intersection-of-a-sphere-and-a-plane-knowing-equations/539032#539032.

Comment: @g.kov  I am sorry. I want to ask you that,  can you draw dashed lines in the second link?

Comment: @minhthien_2016: I see. OK, I'll try to post an answer to that question.

Comment: @minhthien_2016:I've posted [an answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/569030/27243),
where the cross section boundary is split automatically
into the front and the back curves.

Comment: @g.kov Thank you very much.

Comment: @g.kov In Asymptote, ingeneral, how to find intersection of a plane passing through three points `A, B, C` with the line though two points `M, N`?

Comment: @minhthien_2016 As docs say, there is a function for this:

`real intersect(triple P, triple Q, triple n, triple Z);`
returns the intersection time of the extension of the line segment PQ with the
plane perpendicular to n and passing through Z.

Comment: @g.kov Thank you very much.

Comment: @g.kov Can you help me make a simple file: Let be given a pyramid `SABCD`, `ABSD` is a square. `E` is midpoint `AB`,  `F` is midpoint `BC`,  `G` is midpoint `SD`. Find the intersection `X` of the line `AD` and plane `EFG`.?

Comment: @g.kov Thanks. I am trying to draw it.

Comment: @minhthien_2016:Perhaps, I can, but it is not a good practice here on MSE to ask and answer a new questions in a comment section under an old one. I'm pretty sure that you will get a set of nice answers, if you ask this as a proper new question, adding your attempts and the description of the difficulties you've found. 
Also note that in the question as it's stated, $AD\parallel FG$,
hence, $AD\parallel EFG$, that is no intersection (except at $\infty$).

Comment: @g.kov I posted new question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/577053/how-can-i-rotate-a-figure-drawing-with-asymptote-and-hidden-parts-dashed-is-chan)

Answer (score 9):

Here's a metapost version, unfortunately without altering the out of the box `luamplib` package, I can't seem to draw dashed lines so I've replaced them with lighter lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
u:=2cm;
path p[];
pair A,B,C,D,E,H,I,K,M,N,O,S,t;
def de = withcolor .85white enddef;

beginfig(1);
k = 2.5u;
p1 = unitsquare slanted .3 xscaled 2u yscaled u;
B = point 0 of p1;
C = point 1 of p1;
D = point 2 of p1;
A = point 3 of p1;
S = A shifted (0,k*length (A--B));
M = .5[A,S];
O = .5[A,C];
N = whatever[B,M]=whatever[S,B shifted (0,k*length (A--B))];
I = (N--C) intersectionpoint (S--D);
H = whatever[S,O] = A + whatever*((S-O) rotated 90);
E = whatever[S,D] = A + whatever*((S-D) rotated 90);
K = E shifted (B-A);
t = (B--N) intersectionpoint (S--D);

draw O--A--S--O--B--A--D--O--C de;
draw A--E de;
draw M--I de;
draw A--H de;
draw B--t de;
draw S--C--B--K--E--S--N--C--D;
draw B--S--D;
draw t--N--K;

dotlabel.llft("B",B);
dotlabel.urt("D",D);
dotlabel.lrt("C",C);
dotlabel.ulft("A",A);
dotlabel.ulft("S",S);
dotlabel.top("N",N);
dotlabel.bot("O",O);
dotlabel.rt("I",I);
dotlabel.ulft("H",H);
dotlabel.urt("E",E);
dotlabel.lrt("K",K);
dotlabel.lrt("M",M);

endfig;
end;

\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I copied Alain Matthes' code with some prepaired.

```
\documentclass[border=2cm]{standalone}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
 \usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}
\usepackage{fouriernc}

 \tikzset{ hidden/.style = {thin, dashed}}
   \tikzset{%
     add/.style args={#1 and #2}{
         to path={%
  ($(\tikztostart)!-#1!(\tikztotarget)$)--($(\tikztotarget)!-#2!(\tikztostart)$)%
   \tikztonodes}}}

 \begin{document}

 \tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{100}
  %\tdplotsetmaincoords{80}{100} 
 \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=1.5]
 \pgfmathsetmacro\a{3}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\b{3}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\h}{{\a*sqrt(2)}}

 % definitions 
    \path (0,0,0)                           coordinate (A) 
          (\a,0,0)                          coordinate (B) 
          (\a,\b,0)                         coordinate (C) 
          (0,\b,0)                          coordinate (D) 
          (0,0,\h)                          coordinate (S) 
           ($(S)!0.5!(A)$)                  coordinate (M) 
         ($(C)!0.5!(A)$)                    coordinate (O) 
          ($(S)!0.5!(D)$)                   coordinate (I) 
          ({2*\h^2*\a/(\a^2+\b^2+4*\h^2)}, {2*\b*\h^2/(\a^2+\b^2+4*\h^2)}, {\h*(\a^2+\b^2)/(\a^2+\b^2+4*\h^2)})    coordinate (H)
          (-\a, 0, \h)                     coordinate (N)
          (0, {\b*\h^2/(\b^2+\h^2)},{ \b^2*\h/(\b^2+\h^2)})         coordinate (E)
           (\a, {\b*\h^2/(\b^2+\h^2)}, {\b^2*\h/(\b^2+\h^2)})        coordinate (K) ;
 % drawing
 \begin{scope}
    \clip (S) -- (B) -- (D) --cycle;
    \draw[hidden] (B) -- (N);
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}
    \clip (S) -- (I) -- (N) --cycle;
    \draw (B) -- (N);
 \end{scope}

 \draw[hidden] 
       (A) -- (C)  (A) -- (B)  (A) -- (D) (A) -- (H) (A) -- (S)
      (A) -- (E) (B) -- (D)  (O) -- (S) (I) -- (M);
 \draw[thick] (B) -- (K) -- (E)   (C) -- (N) -- (K)
       (B) --(C) -- (D) (S) -- (D)  (S) -- (B)  (S) -- (C);
 \draw[add = 1 and 1]  (S) to (N); 

 % place black circles and labels
 \foreach \point/\position in {A/left,B/left,C/right,D/right,E/right,H/above,
   I/right,K/right,M/right,N/left,O/right,S/left}
 {
   \fill (\point) circle (1.2pt);
   \node[\position=3pt] at (\point) {$\point$};
 }

 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]