# How can I rotate a figure drawing with Asymptote and hidden parts dashed is changed automatically?

Tags: asymptote

I draw this picture with Asymptote (the first time). My code

```
    import three; import graph3; import math; import patterns;
size(5cm); dotfactor =3.5;
defaultpen(fontsize(9pt));
currentprojection =
orthographic((5,2,3));
triple A, B, C, D, S, E, F, G;
D = O; A = X; B = X+Y; C = Y; S=Z; E=0.5(A+B); F=0.5(B+C); G=0.5(S+D);
pen dashed=linetype(new real[] {5,5}); // set up dashed pattern
pen visLine=darkblue+0.8pt;
pen hidLine=lightblue+dashed+0.8pt;

//pen linePen=darkblue+1.3bp;
pen dotPen= darkblue+3bp;
//pen dashPen=1bp+linetype(new real[]{4,3})+linecap(0);

draw(A--B--C,visLine);
draw(S--B^^S--C^^S--A,visLine);
draw(S--D^^A--D--C,hidLine);
real k= intersect(S,A, cross(G-E, G-F),G);
triple M=(1-k)*S+k*A; 
triple N=(1-k)*S+k*C; 
dot("$S$",S,dir(90),dotPen); 
dot("$A$",A,dir(-90),dotPen); 
dot("$B$",B,dir(-90),dotPen);
dot("$C$",C,dir(-90),dotPen); 
dot("$D$",D,dir(-90),dotPen);
dot("$E$",E,dir(-90),dotPen);
dot("$F$",F,dir(-90),dotPen);
dot("$G$",G,dir(0),dotPen);
dot("$M$",M,dir(120),dotPen);
dot("$N$",N,dir(30),dotPen);
draw(M--G--N^^ E -- F,hidLine);
draw(M--E^^ N -- F,visLine);
//filldraw(G--M--E--F--N--cycle,pattern(" hatch" ));
```

[image]

Now I want to rotate the above picture like this

[image]

(The above picture is drawn with TikZ, see [here](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1585))

Thank to marmot let me using this gif.

[image]

How can I rotate the figure (in Asymptote) and hidden parts dashed is changed automatically?

Comment: Happy new year 2021! `23:00:00` :-)

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Question: Would you be satisfied to have the hidden parts as solid gray lines rather than dashed black lines?

Comment: @CharlesStaats Can I get dashed black lines?

Comment: @CharlesStaats If they can not, then I am be satified to have the hidden parts as solid gray lines.

Comment: @minhthien_2016 The solid gray lines are much easier; all you have to do is add semi-transparent white surfaces for all the planes. This also allows compounding -- a line behind two surfaces will be lighter than a line behind only one surface.

Comment: Can you slow down the speed of spinning! Thank you

Comment: @CharlesStaats Can I post [this question](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1637) to Asymptote?