# How to calculate with two same macros in pgfmath?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, pgfmath

I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20009/63604) answer from the User Caramdir and am actually trying to fit the code to my needs. There's something like this

```
\newcommand\definePointByXYZ[4]{
    %\coordinate (#1) at (#2,#3,#4);
    \expandafter\gdef\csname tsx@point@#1\endcsname{
        \def\tsx@point@x{#2}
        \def\tsx@point@y{#3}
        \def\tsx@point@z{#4}
    }
}

% Define a plane.
% #1 = name of the plane
% #2*x + #3*y + #4*z = #5 is the equation of the plane
\newcommand*\definePlaneByEquation[5]{
    \expandafter\gdef\csname tsx@plane@#1\endcsname{
        \def\tsx@plane@xcoeff{#2}
        \def\tsx@plane@ycoeff{#3}
        \def\tsx@plane@zcoeff{#4}
        \def\tsx@plane@scalar{#5}
    }
}

% Project a point to a plane.
% #1 = name of the new point
% #2 = name of old point
% #3 = name of plane
\newcommand\projectPointToPlane[3]{{
    \csname tsx@point@#2\endcsname
    \csname tsx@plane@#3\endcsname
% ...
}}
```

In the command `projectPointToPlane` the arguments are two points that get defined by \definePointByXYZ and then it's possible to calculate anything, for example:

```
\pgfmathparse{\tsx@plane@xcoeff*\tsx@plane@xcoeff + \tsx@plane@ycoeff*\tsx@plane@ycoeff + \tsx@plane@zcoeff*\tsx@plane@zcoeff}
    \let\nnormsq\pgfmathresult
```

Now I'd like to create something like this

```
% #1 = Name of the object
% #2 = Point A
% #2 = Point B
\newcommand*\mynewcommand[3]{
   \csname tsx@point@#2\endcsname
   \csname tsx@point@#3\endcsname
   % Calculate something
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\myvariable}{%any expression}
}
```

My Question: How can I calculate with the coordinates of two Points? Is it even possible? My first try was to rename one line to `\csname tsx@pointtwo@#3\endcsname` and then

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myvariable}{\tsx@point@x *\tsxpointtwo@x}
```

but that didn't work. I'm new to TeX-Programming, so any help is really appreciated. :)

Comment: It's not very clear what "Point A" and "Point B" are. Are they coordinate names? If so you need to extract the `x` `y` values from them using `\newdim\mypointx \pgfextractx\mypointx{\pgfpointachor{PointA}{center}}`, the same for `y`, then you can use `\mypointx` and `\mypointy` in your calculations. If "Point A" and B are something else, then what are they exactly?

Comment: "Point A" and "Point B" are two Points that get defined by `\definePointByXYZ`. For  example: `\definePointByXYZ{A}{1}{2}{3}` and `\definePointByXYZ{B}{1}{4}{2}`defines points named A and B with the coordinates x=1,y=2,z=3 and x=1,y=4,z=2. Then I can use `\mynewcommand{...}{A}{B}`.  Now I want to calculate with the coordinates of the both points inside my `\mynewcommand` similar to `\projectPlaneToPoint` from the linked answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `\csname tsx@point@#1 \endcsname` defines all `\tsx@point@x`, `y` and `z`, once you call `\csname tsx@point@#2 \endcsname` it defines them *again* overwriting the previous values, so you're left with only the coordinates of the last issued `tsx@point@#1`.

One way to get around this is to `\let\first@point@x\tsx@point@x` and so on for `y` and `z` before calling the other `\csname tsx@point@#2\endcsname`, then you can access the first declared point through the `\first@point@<x,y,z>` holder.

## MWE

```
% #1 = Name of the object
% #2 = Point A
% #2 = Point B
\newcommand*\mynewcommand[3]{
   \csname tsx@point@#2\endcsname
   \let\first@point@x\tsx@point@x
   \let\first@point@y\tsx@point@y
   \let\first@point@z\tsx@point@z
   \csname tsx@point@#3\endcsname
   % Calculate something
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\sumofpointsx}{\tsx@point@x+\first@point@x}
}
```

## EDIT

You could so this without using custom commands to define the points. PGF has the `\pgfextract<x,y,z>` command, so if you say `\coordinate (A) at (1,2,3)` you can access these values through:

```
\newdim\mypointx\pgfextractx{\mypointx}{\pgfpointanchor{A}{center}}
\newdim\mypointy\pgfextracty{\mypointy}{\pgfpointanchor{A}{center}}
\newdim\mypointz\pgfextractz{\mypointz}{\pgfpointanchor{A}{center}}
```

### MWE using `\pgfextract<x,y,z>`

```
\newdim\lastx\newdim\lasty\newdim\lastz
\newcommand*{\extracXYZ}[1]{%
    \pgfextractx{\lastx}{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}
    \pgfextracty{\lasty}{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}
    \pgfextractz{\lastz}{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}
}

...

\coordinate (A) at (1,2,3);
\coordinate (B) at (3,2,1);
\newcommand*\mynewcommand[2]{
   \ectractXYZ{#1}
   \let\firstx\lastx
   \let\firsty\lasty
   \let\firstz\lastz
   \ectractXYZ{#2}
   % Calculate something
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\sumofpointsx}{\firstx+\lastx}
}
```

Comment: `\newdim` doesn't seem to exist. Subsituting `\newdimen`, then `\pgfextractz` doesn't exist either . . .

Comment: That is strange... which packges are you loading?